# how to use navigation controller in detail view of split view application for ipad

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, ipad

i am now displaying some table view in root view and detail view now i want to navigate to next view from detail  view when a row get selected in detail view ...

how to create navigation controller in split view and loading the detail view

Thanks in advance..

Comment: This is nothing to do with Xcode - Xcode is just an IDE - you should probably tag it with `iphone`, `ipad`, `ios`, `cocoa-touch` as appropriate.